# How to ignore some properties for being shown when returning object class?

Tags: c#, class, properties, visualization, endpoint

I have this class in `C#`:

```
public class PlayerProfile : BaseDataModel
{
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String AccountType { get; set; }
    public String UserEmail { get; set; }
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String Country { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public String Passphrase { get; set; }
    public Wallet Wallet { get; set; }
    public List<String> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to ignore `PasswordHash` and `PasswordSalt` when I retrieve the full `PlayerProfile` class on one of the endpoints I have.

How can I achieve this behaviour? It would only be for visualisation. I have used an attribute before (I don't remember which one it was) that completely removed those properties from the object and it was not possible to initialise them (that's not the behaviour I want).

Answer (score 0):

I think if U use Child VO(DTO) THEN it will solve.

public class ChildDTO extends PlayerProfile {

```
private String childValue = "";

public String getChildValue() {
    return childValue;
}

public void setChildValue(String childValue) {
    this.childValue = childValue;
}
```

}